# What comes first on Exchange Quota or Vacation message?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, email-server, hosted-exchange

If I have a vacation message set in Exchange and I am over quota, will people get my vacation message or will they just get the exceeded quota message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the receiving user is over their receive quota, the sending user will receive a bounceback.

If the sender received the auto-reply (out of office message), they would assume that the message was received, which isn't the case, since the recipient was over quota.